# Issue after transferring wordpress site

Tags: mysql, wordpress, web

I’ve moved my WP site from my xaamp server to a live server. Sadly it didn’t go smoothly. For some reason my child theme isn’t working. It says it cannot find the parent theme and offers to install it. I’ve since tried deleting the parent theme and installing the parent theme by clicking the button offered. But the issue is the same. It all worked perfectly on my localhost. What did I miss?

Comment: How does the header of style.css in child theme look like?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your child theme directory name doesn't contains any space if it is ok then check style file header

/*
 Theme Name:   Twenty Fifteen Child
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fifteen-child/
 Description:  Twenty Fifteen Child Theme
 Author:       John Doe
 Author URI:   example url
 Template:     twentyfifteen
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  license url
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  twenty-fifteen-child
*/

```
--You will need to replace the example text with the details relevant to your theme.
--The Template line corresponds to the directory name of the parent theme. The parent theme in our example is the Twenty Fifteen theme, so the Template will be twentyfifteen. You may be working with a different theme, so adjust accordingly.
--The only required child theme file is style.css, but functions.php is necessary to enqueue styles correctly (below).
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Template same as parent theme in child theme style file.

Please see following Twenty Seventeen Child Theme code

Theme Name:   Twenty Seventeen Child
Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-seventeen-child/
Description:  Twenty Seventeen Child Theme
Author:       John Doe
Author URI:   http://example.com
**Template:     twentyseventeen**
Version:      1.0.0
Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
Text Domain:  twenty-seventeen-child